# Cómo importar un archivo .json en stylus?

Tags: json, stylus

Tengo un problema al querer importar un archivo ".json" en stylus.
Mi árbol de archivos es de la siguiente forma:

```
static/
├── css/
│   ├── stylus/
|   │   ├── style.styl
│   ├── style.css
│   └── normalize.css
└── json/
    └── media-queries.json
```

Y dentro de mi archivo **"style.styl"** inserto la siguiente línea:

```
json('..\..\json\media-queries.json')
```

Se puede ver en la documentación oficial en el siguiente apartado que se encuentra casi al final de la misma: **#json(path[, options])**
http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html

El error que me sale en la terminal es el siguiente:

> ```
> Error: style.styl:1:37
>    1| json('..\..\json\media-queries.json')
> ------------------------------------------^
> failed to locate .json file ..\..\json\media-queries
> ```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Intenta escribir el `path` usando `/` (barra) en lugar de \ (barra invertida), es decir, así `json('../../json/media-queries.json')`

Comment: Intenté lo que me sugerio y ahora me tira otro error: "Unexpected token /"

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que el contenido del archivo `JSON` es válido? Prueba copiar y pegar su contenido en [esta web](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: Usted tenia razón, el problema era que tenia comentarios en el archivo ".json" cuando se los saque me compilo, ahora la pregunta es como poner comentarios en un archivo json?

Comment: No, no se pueden poner comentarios en archivos `JSON`. Cualquier dudad mira [estas respuestas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json)

Comment: Es que en realidad la solución no fue la barra invertida, era el archivo 'JSON' el que estaba mal y por eso no compilaba.

Comment: No, eran las 2 cosas, porque cuando cambiaste las barras, después salto el error `Unexpected token /`

Comment: Ah es cierto, perdón por ello, ahí lo voto! gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta escribir el `path` al archivo `JSON` usando `/` (barra) en lugar de `\` (barra invertida).

Así por ejemplo:

```
json('../../json/media-queries.json')
```